# How can you set the background image in CSS to use a defined SVG pattern?

Tags: css, svg

HTML:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <svg-pattern-of-some-sort id="my-pattern" />
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="box"></box>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: ...;
  height: ...;
  background-image: url(#my-pattern)
}
```

How can you make this work?

An SVG element can use an SVG pattern as `fill`, and `background-image` can point to a `.svg`, but how do you enable a DOM element to take an SVG (written in HTML) as it's background -- without complex Base-64 conversion etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SVG directly in the CSS:

```
.box {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...> ... </svg>');
}
```

No need for Base64 conversion... of course there will be some browsers with issues understanding such syntax.